# Построчное заполнение таблицы на странице сайта

Tags: javascript, php, html

У меня есть вот такой код, как сделать так чтобы у таблицы автоматически добавлялась новая строка для заполнения как только я закончу предыдущую?

```
    <?php
$column_one = [
    "1" => "Максим",
    "2" => "Василий",
    "3" => "Евгений",
    "4" => "Владимир",
];
$column_two = [
    "1" => "Евтушенко",
    "2" => "Петров",
    "3" => "Долгополов",
    "4" => "Неуструев",
];
$column_three = [
    "1" => "1",
    "2" => "2",
    "3" => "3",
    "4" => "4",
];
$column_four = [
    "1" => "1",
    "2" => "2",
    "3" => "3",
    "4" => "4",
];
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>


<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style1.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/SidePanel.css" type="text/css">
  <script defer src="../JavaScript/step.js "> </script>
</head>


<body>
<?php require "../blocks/SidePanel.php" ?>

  <div class="fullscr">
    <?php
    $step = 0;
    echo "<table class=\"style1\">";
    if ($step == 0) {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>1 столбик</td>";
        echo "<td>2 столбик</td>";
        echo "<td>3 столбик</td>";
        echo "<td>4 столбик</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
      if ($step == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><select name=\"one\" id =\"one\" onChange=\"HiddenOne();\">";
          //echo "<option hidden></option>";
          foreach ($column_one as $key => $value) {

            echo "<option>$value</option>";
          }
        echo "</select></td>";
        $step ++;
      }
        if ($step == 1) {
          echo "<td><select hidden name=\"two\" id =\"two\" onChange=\"HiddenTwo();\">";
            foreach ($column_two as $key => $value) {
              echo "<option>$value</option>";
            }
          echo "</td></select>";
          $step ++;
        }
          if ($step == 2) {
            echo "<td><select hidden name=\"three\" id =\"three\" onChange=\"HiddenThree();\">";
              foreach ($column_three as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option>$value</option>";
              }
            echo "</td></select>";
            $step ++;
          }
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<input hidden id=\"myInput\" placeholder=\"text\" onChange=\"HiddenInput();\" class=\"simpleCart_input\"></input>";
            echo "<input hidden type=\"button\" id=\"ButtmyInput\" value=\"ОК\" onclick=\"HiddenButtmyInput();\"></input>";
            echo "</td>";
            if ($step == 3) {
              echo "<td><select hidden name=\"four\" id =\"four\" onChange=\"HiddenFour();\">";
                foreach ($column_four as $key => $value) {
                  echo "<option>$value</option>";
                }
              echo "</td></select>";
              $step ++;
            }

        echo "</tr>";
      echo "</table>";
    ?>
    <div class="test">
      просто текст
    </div>
  </div>

</body>


</html>
```

выглядит она вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: js в помощь... покажите наработки свои, иначе это просто задание

Comment: собственно у вас уже все сделано: последовательно вызываются HiddenOne(), HiddenTwo()... в последнем Hidden() нужно сделать копию предыдущей строки tbody.appendChild(tr.cloneNode(true)), ну либо полностью повторить на JS код PHP